# How do I change my username?

Tags: support

I signed in with Google and I didn't get to choose my user name, is there a way to change it?

I cannot find a button under my profile.

Comment: I had the same problem once :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to [the main site](http://askubuntu.com) and click your user at the top of the page

> [image]

Now choose the tab `Edit profile and settings`

> [image]

Here you can change your `display name` (this is the user name) and picture etc...

When you are finished, don't forget to click `save profile` at the bottom of the page.

> [image]